# How to await for one task on two different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, c#-7.0

Can I await on a Task that was created on a different thread? For example:

```
...
CurrentIteration = Execute(); // returns Task
await CurrentIteration;
...
```

And then, on another thread:

```
...
await CurrentIteration;
...
```

1. Will the second thread wait for method Execute to finish executing?
2. If it will, will I be able to re-use CurrentIteration for the same purpose in the second thread, given that I re-run

`CurrentIteration = Execute(); // returns Task
    await CurrentIteration;`

On the first thread?

I tried this code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {

        var instance = new SomeClass();
        var task = instance.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("thread 1 waiting...");
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread 2 started... waiting...");
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine("thread 2 ended!!!!!");
        });

        await task;

        Console.WriteLine("thread 1 done!!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task Execute()
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    }
}
```

But it prints

```
thread 1 waiting...
thread 2 started... waiting...
```

then

```
thread 1 done!!
```

but never `thread 2 ended!!!!!`. Why is that? How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: You're not awaiting the task you're starting. In fact, you should be getting a warning in intellisense telling you just that. If you don't await it, sometimes it will execute before `thread 1 done`, sometimes it won't.

Comment: you mean I should put `await` before `Task.Run...`?

Comment: That's correct, yes

Comment: yeah but what if I want it to run on a different thread?

Comment: in order to test if I can await for a task concurrently, from different places?

Comment: You can write something like this: `var otherTask = Task.Run...` and at the end write (after `await task`) `await OtherTask`. Though you seem to be conflating the ideas between async/await and multithreading. Your code will work (sometimes), but adding `await otherTask` before `Console.ReadKey()` means we're *sure* the other task will be finished before blocking the IO.

Comment: why wouldn't `await Task.Run` block the main thread until the task it has returned has ended?

Comment: You assign the task, and only await it later.

Comment: no, if I use `await Task.Run`, I would be waiting for it.

Comment: Please read the comment again, I am suggesting writing `var something = Task.Run(...` and just before your console.readkey, `await something`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `await` on a task from multiple threads. You were actually really close to get that to work, as @Rob said, you just needed to `await` the second thread.

consider this:

```
    public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {

        var instance = new SomeClass();
        var task = instance.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("thread 1 waiting...");
        var secondTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread 2 started... waiting...");
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine("thread 2 ended!!!!!");
        });

        await task;

        await secondTask;

        Console.WriteLine("thread 1 done!!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Add the wait on your second thread after you finish waiting for the task.

The reason you didn't see the indication is because the console got stuck on the `ReadKey` method, and couldn't write anything until it's finished. If you would've pressed Enter, you can see the "thread 2 ended!!!!!" line for a second before the app closes.